# Try to simulate first.py of ns3 using netanim

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, ns-3

Can you please help me out about the below error
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.32/ns-3.32$ ./waf --pyrun scratch/first.py
Waf: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.32/ns-3.32/build'               Waf: Leaving directory` /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.32/ns-3.32/build'
Build commands will be stored in build/compile_commands.json
'build' finished successfully (1.500s)
File "scratch/first.py", line 66
AnimationInterface netanim ("my_first.xml")
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

how can I fix this error please?

Comment: What does `scratch/first.py` look like? `AnimationInterface netanim ("my_first.xml")` is indeed invalid syntax.

Comment: ok. what is the right syntax? @ForceBru

Comment: It's impossible to tell without a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the Python bindings, but take a look at [this page](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/python.html) from the manual. You will probably need to do something along the lines of

```cpp
anim = ns.netanim.AnimationInterface("my_first.xml")
```